# What is the Universal Translator censoring?

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry

> Lieutenant, launch the polar probes!
>
> Launching probes, sir. Failure, sir. Probes did not land at the poles.
>
> Well!? Where are they?
>
> Unknown, sir. Somewhere off-axis. They did land on opposite sides of
>   the planet.
>
> Launch another pair!
>
> Another failure, sir. Same thing. They are opposite each other, but
>   not at the poles.
>
> Same places as the first pair?
>
> No, sir.  Completely different.
>
> Dammit, find them. Tachyon ranging pulse!
>
> All probes responding. Linear distances from ship are 7, 9, 11, and
>   [CENSORED] SDUs*.
>
> (new voice) HAHAHAHAHA
>
> Ensign! What is so funny?
>
> Sir, at our current altitude, the area of the planet's surface we can
>   see is exactly equal to the area of a flat circle of [CENSORED]
>   radius! Funny coincidence, sir.
>
> Shut up, Wesley!

*SDU : Standard Distance Unit

Comment: Is the implication that both censored numbers are the same?

Comment: I'm trying to decide if it's Wesley Crusher or if "Sir" is the robot from Clone High.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, yes, the number being censored happens to be an unfathomable insult in Galactic Common, and for the sake of peace, it is always filtered by the Universal Translator

Comment: Bet they are making an 455 of themselves

Comment: Can we assume that the first two distances refer to the first two probes?

Comment: Alternatively, can we assume that the probes responded in order of distance, so [CENSORED] is greater than 11?

Comment: You don't need to assume either of those.

Comment: @EngineerToast,@Kevin "[CENSORED]" was merely said last due to the natural reluctance of anyone to utter such unspeakable words. The other distances are also listed in no particular order.

Comment: 13 or 42 or nothing  >_<

Comment: So, one of the probes landed in Belgium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The censored number is

> 3

Here is a cross section of the planet containing all four probes, illustrating some terms:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

To clarify, the distances to the four probes are $D_{A^+},D_{A^-},D_{B^+},$ and $D_{B^-}$, and these four are some rearrangement of the numbers $7,9,11$, and [CENSORED]. Without loss of generality, assume
$$
D_{A^+}=[CENSORED]
$$
Now, applying Law of Cosines to the triangle with angle $\varphi$, we get
$$
D_{A^-}^2=H^2+R^2-2RH\cos\varphi
$$
and in the same vein,
$$
D_{A^+}^2=H^2+R^2-2RH\cos(180-\varphi)=H^2+R^2+2RH\cos\varphi.
$$
Adding these together,
$$
D_{A^-}^2+D_{A^+}^2=2R^2+2H^2\tag{1}
$$
Similarly,
$$
D_{B^-}^2+D_{B^+}^2=2R^2+2H^2\tag2
$$
Combining (1) and (2), we get that $D_{A^+}^2=D_{B^+}^2+D_{B^-}^2-D_{A^-}^2$, so the three possibilities for $D_{A^+}^2$ are
$$
11^2+9^2-7^2=153\qquad 7^2+11^2-9^2=89\qquad 9^2+7^2-11^2=9
$$
The left two cases **would imply that $D_{A^+}$ was one of the larger two distances** among $7,9,11$ and [CENSORED] (since $\sqrt{153}>\sqrt{89}>9$).

What are we to make of the Wesley's statement? The area they can see is at most half the planet's area, so at most $2\pi R^2$. Since Wesley said this is equal to $\pi\times[CENSORED]^2$, it follows that $\pi\times[CENSORED]^2\le 2\pi R^2$, so
$$
[CENSORED]^2=D_{A^+}^2\le 2R^2\le R^2+H^2\tag 3
$$
since $R\le H$. Combining (1) and (3), we see that $$D_{A^-}^2=2R^2+2H^2-D_{A^+}^2\ge R^2+H^2\ge D_{A^+}^2$$ so that $D_{A^+}$ is the *smaller* of the two $A$ probe distances. This means that the above **bold** statement cannot be true, so that we must have $D_{A^+}^2=9$, giving us the answer as claimed.

We can also make an educated guess as to *why* this number is so vulgar:

> it looks like a sideways butt.

Comment: Good job! But I demand you apologize for the repeated swearing in this answer.

Comment: Nice :-) The reason I'm proud of this puzzle is because the radius of the planet, the altitude of the ship, and the distances between the probes are all still indeterminate, but [CENSORED] is always the same.

Comment: @Anon Yeah, this is pretty satisfying! Is this one of your creation?

Comment: Yes, it's my creation.  Glad you enjoyed it.

Answer (score 1):

### PARTIAL ANSWER

This how far I've gotten. I hope someone with more a recent education than I can take correct what I have wrong and finish it up.

---

### tl;dr

Here are pieces I think will help:
$$D_A^2=49=r_P^2+z_S^2-2z_Sz_A$$
$$D_B^2=81=r_P^2+z_S^2-2z_Sz_B$$
$$D_C^2=121=r_P^2+z_S^2-2z_Sz_C$$
$$D_D^2=??=r_P^2+z_S^2-2z_Sz_D$$
$$5z_A-9z_B+4z_C=0$$
$$\frac{1}{z_S}=\frac{z_A-z_B}{4}=\frac{z_A-z_C}{9}=\frac{z_B-z_C}{5}$$
$$r_C^2=2r_Ph$$
$$r_P^2=\pm(x_Ax_B+y_Ay_B+z_Az_B)$$
$$r_P^2=\pm(x_Cx_D+y_Cy_D+z_Cz_D)$$

---

Name the 4 points A, B, C, D and their coordinates as $(x_A,y_A,z_A)$, etc.
Name the ship S and its coordinates are $(x_S,y_S,z_S)$
Name the planet P and its coordinates are $(x_P,y_P,z_P)$ with a radius $r_P$

For convenience, set the center of the planet $P$ to be at the origin.
In addition, orient the axes such that the ship $S$ is directly above the planet along the z-axis.

This tells us that $x_P=y_P=z_P=x_S=y_S=0$

The general equation for the distance between two points in 3D space is
$$D=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}$$
Therefore, the distance between the ship $S$ and point $A$ is
$$D_A=7=\sqrt{(x_S-x_A)^2+(y_S-y_A)^2+(z_S-z_A)^2}$$
$$D_A=7=\sqrt{(0-x_A)^2+(0-y_A)^2+(z_S-z_A)^2}$$
$$D_A=7=\sqrt{x_A^2+y_A^2+(z_S^2-2z_Sz_A+z_A^2)}$$
$$D_A=7=\sqrt{(x_A^2+y_A^2+z_A^2)+(z_S^2-2z_Sz_A)}$$

Now, since the planet's center is at the origin, we know $x_A^2+y_A^2+z_A^2=r_P^2$
We can plug that in and square both sides to get
$$D_A^2=49=r_P^2+z_S^2-2z_Sz_A$$
It is trivial to expand that to the other 3 points
$$D_B^2=81=r_P^2+z_S^2-2z_Sz_B$$
$$D_C^2=121=r_P^2+z_S^2-2z_Sz_C$$
$$D_D^2=??=r_P^2+z_S^2-2z_Sz_D$$

Right now, we're sitting at 4 equations and 7 unknowns ($r_P,z_S,z_A,z_B,z_C,z_D,D_D$). That's close but we're not there yet. We can play around with the formulas for $D_A$ and $D_B$ because they're values are known.
$$D_A^2+32 = 49+32=81=D_B^2$$
$$r_P^2+z_S^2-2z_Sz_A+32=r_P^2+z_S^2-2z_Sz_B$$
$$-2z_Sz_A+32=-2z_Sz_B$$
$$2z_Sz_B+32=2z_Sz_A$$
$$z_Sz_B+16=z_Sz_A$$
We can do the same thing for $D_A$ and $D_C$ as well as $D_B$ and $D_C$
$$z_Sz_C+36=z_Sz_A$$
$$z_Sz_C+20=z_Sz_B$$
If we solve all three for $z_S$, we can set them equal.
$$z_S=16/(z_A-z_B)=36/(z_A-z_C)=20/(z_B-z_C)$$
$$z_S=4/(z_A-z_B)=9/(z_A-z_C)=5/(z_B-z_C)$$
$$\frac{1}{z_S}=\frac{z_A-z_B}{4}=\frac{z_A-z_C}{9}=\frac{z_B-z_C}{5}$$
This gives us the relationship
$$5z_A-9z_B+4z_C=0$$

---

Let's look at the second observation. The formula for the surface area a [spherical cap](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html) $A_P$ that is distance $h$ from the origin and the area of a circle $A_C$ are  given by
$$A_P=2\pi r_Ph$$
$$A_C=\pi r_C^2$$
We're told those are equal so we can drop the $\pi$ to get the equality
$$r_C^2=2r_Ph$$

Unfortunately, this introduces only 1 new equation and 2 new unknowns. I think the solution will involve some trig to find $h$ based on $r_P$, $z_S$, and tangent lines but I don't have the brainpower for that right now.

---

I'm sure that the probes landing on opposite sides matters but I couldn't get it to do anything useful because it added more unknowns instead of removing them. Here's what I wrote for that section:

We also know that the probes landed on opposite sides of the sphere. That means the line connecting them passes through the center which means it is of length $2r_P$. That gives us the following for the distance between probe $A$ and $B$. **(Here I have to assume that the first two distances are for the first two probes. If that's not the case, this section must be reworked.)**
$$2r_P=\sqrt{(x_A-x_B)^2+(y_A-y_B)^2+(z_A-z_B)^2}$$
$$2r_P=\sqrt{(x_A^2-2x_Ax_B+x_B^2)+(y_A^2-2y_Ay_B+y_B^2)+(z_A^2-2z_Az_B+z_B^2)}$$
$$2r_P=\sqrt{(x_A^2+y_A^2+z_A^2)+(x_B^2+y_B^2+z_B^2)-2(x_Ax_B+y_Ay_B+z_Az_B)}$$
$$2r_P=\sqrt{(r_P^2)+(r_P^2)-2(x_Ax_B+y_Ay_B+z_Az_B)}$$
$$2r_P=\sqrt{2r_P^2-2(x_Ax_B+y_Ay_B+z_Az_B)}$$
$$4r_P^2=\pm2(r_P^2-(x_Ax_B+y_Ay_B+z_Az_B))$$
$$r_P^2=\pm(x_Ax_B+y_Ay_B+z_Az_B)$$

(I'm not super-confident in how the $\pm$ comes in once you square both sides but I think it has to be considered somewhere.)

We can do the same thing for the other two probes
$$r_P^2=\pm(x_Cx_D+y_Cy_D+z_Cz_D)$$

Comment: I can verify that this solution is way overcomplicating things. You're getting bogged down in algebra without a strategy for handling the equations.